# How to query an index for documents that match an or condition?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example lets say I have a resources index with type resource and it has a property named status which can hold a value 1,2 or 3.

How do I make a query that will retrieve all documents with status = 1 **OR** status = 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string in elasticsearch for this kind of query(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "status",
            "query" : "1 OR 2 OR 3"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although above query works well, I'd rather prefer using `terms` query over `full-text` query for **structured fields**(not_analyzed) like `status`. Equivalent terms query is: `GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "status": [1, 2]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Agree with @avr

Comment: What about doing a filter? Is that doable as well?

Comment: For combining multiple filters , you can go through at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html